# Trigger for Audit Table in Sybase ASE 15.7

Tags: triggers, sybase, audit

I'm trying to create a trigger that records info on insertions, updates, and deletions. To make things simple I'm simply trying to create a trigger for insertions without including info such as user and date.

My referenced table is with columns:

### DefaultProperties

-DefaultPropertiesID

-Key_

-Value

-ProcessID_FK (foreign key)

============================

and my audit table is:

### DefaultProperties_Audit

-OldDefaultID

-OldKey_

-OldValue

-OldProcessID_FK

The code for my current trigger is:

```
create trigger DPTrigger on DefaultProperties
   for insert as
   begin
       insert into DefaultProperties_Audit(OldDefaultID, OldKey_, OldValue, OldPid_FK, Modifier, EntryDate, Operation)
       select DefaultPropertiesID, Key_, Value, ProcessID_FK, user_name(), GETDATE(), 'insertion' from inserted
   end
```

but how do I do something like this?

```
create trigger DPTrigger on DefaultProperties
    for insert, update, delete as
    if insert then
        begin
            insert into DefaultProperties_Audit(OldDefaultID, OldKey_, OldValue, OldPid_FK, Modifier, EntryDate, Operation)
            select DefaultPropertiesID, Key_, Value, ProcessID_FK, user_name(), GETDATE(), 'insertion' from inserted
        end
    endif
    if update then
        doSomething()
    endif
    if delete then
        doSomethingElse()
    endif
```

When I try to compile my version of the above, it throws me an error. I understand an alternative is to create three separate triggers for insert, update, and delete. I was just wondering if I can condense it into one?

Also, it seems like I can condense it into one if I explicitly state 
    if update(col1) or update(col2) or update(col3)
but that seems to also possibly bring up some errors.

Any tips/hints to make this work and to improve it would be *greatly appreciated*.

Comment: Could you update your question to include which Sybase product (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) you're using, as well as the version?

Comment: You might also want to review your past questions with an eye towards providing feedback via upvoting and/or accepting those answers that helped resolve your questions/issues; sure, it's mostly just a bunch of gamification but some people may choose to spend their time on questions where there's a better chance of feedback

Comment: @markp thanks for the feedback! the product/version is: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASE triggers support the `update()` function; there is no such thing as a `insert()` function.

While the `update()` function can be used for insert triggers, `update()` is typically used in update triggers to determine which columns have been updated.

In this particular case, since you plan on inserting the whole row into your audit table, and obviously (?) all of the columns are new, you'll likely find something like the following to be more useful:

```
create trigger dbo.DPTrigger on dbo.DefaultProperties
    for insert as
    begin
        insert into DefaultProperties_Audit(OldDefaultID, OldKey_, OldValue, OldPid_FK)
        select DefaultPropertiesID, Key_, ProcessID_FK, Value from  inserted
    end
```

For `create trigger` syntax, examples, and some discussion of trigger coding see [ASE - Reference Manual: Commands - create trigger](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X19955.htm)

For more discussion on trigger usage as it pertains to RI and transactional control see [ASE - TSQL Users Guide - Triggers: Enforcing RI constraints](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X79145.htm)

---

As for the updated question asking about consolidating the insert/update/delete code into a single trigger ...

The easiest way to determine if the trigger fired on an insert, update or delete is to test for the existence of rows in the pseudo-tables named `inserted` and `deleted`; you can either test for the existence every time the trigger needs to know the type of parent DML, or test once and store in a @variable:

```
create trigger ...
begin
    declare @operation char(1) -- 'I'nsert, 'U'pdate, 'D'elete
    if exists(select 1 from inserted)
        select @operation = 'I'
    if exists(select 1 from deleted)
        select @operation = case when @operation = 'I' then 'U' else 'D' end

    ... reset of trigger code ...
end
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I had to do the above for it to work (see original question). however, when i am inserting a row into the DefaultProperties table, i get this error -->                                                                              Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into DefaultProperties (Key_, ProcessID_FK, Value) values ('k1', 1, 'v1')
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: The column OldKey_ in table DefaultProperties_Audit does not allow null values.

Comment: Why are you doing 4 separate inserts to the `DefaultProperties_Audit` table?  Do you really want to create 4 separate rows in `DefaultProperites_Audit` for every 1 row inserted to `DefaultProperties`?  If you really want 4 different rows then you'll have to define all columns in `DefaultProperties_Audit` as NULL **or** make sure they have a default value.

Comment: ah makes sense. but when I was trying what you wrote, I got this error: **Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create trigger dbo.DPTrigger on dbo.DefaultProperties
    for insert as
    begin
        insert into DefaultProperties_Audit(OldDefaultID, OldKey_, OldValue, OldPid_FK)
        select (DefaultPropertiesID, Key_, ProcessID_FK, Value) from inserted
    end
Error report -
Incorrect syntax near ','.**

Comment: **\*arg\*** I had cut-n-pasted your original code ... forgot to remove the parens from around the `select`'s column list; I've updated my answer ... try it now

Comment: it works! wonderful. one last thing haha, please see the original post

Comment: I've added a new section to my answer to address how to tell what the parent DML operation was (insert? update? delete?)

Comment: I see, makes sense. seems like to easiest way to do this is to just make 3 separate triggers though. I appreciate all your help!